# How to unnest tuples in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a list of lists of tuples I would like to transform into a pandas data frame.

Each tuple contains the same amount of elements and they are ordered. How can I load this data into a pandas dataframe so each value individually appears in a cell under it's respective?
Original Data Sample:

```
[[(John, Smith),(Jane, Smith)], [(John, Doe),(Jane, Doe)]]
```

Desired Output

```
First| Last
--------------
John | Smith |
Jane | Smith |
John | Doe   |
Jane | Doe   |
```

Comment: I'm ok working with a list of tuples, but not a list of lists of tuples. How would you recommend solving to achieve the desired output above?

Comment: Just do this: `pd.DataFrame(l[0], columns=['First', 'Last'])`, where `l` is your `list of list of tuples`.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([j for i in tups for j in i], columns=['First', 'Last'])` where `tups=[[("John", "Smith"),("Jane", "Smith")], [("John","Doe"),("Jane", "Doe")]]`

Comment: `from itertools import chain; pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(l))`.

Comment: @SaravanakumarV - Thank you. Your explanation is on point and lead me to learn more about list comprehension, which was my initial problem....I knew little about.